# how can i deal with my misbehaving shopping cart

Tags: php, session, shopping-cart

I have a PHP cart that is using sessions. I am using ajax for the add to cart and delete operations. As for now, I can perfectly add products to the session. The problem comes when I delete an item, the items will be successfully deleted, but, the cart misbehaves when I try to add new items after deleting some instead of adding items like before, it will be now updating the first element in the cart.

the code for add to cart is

```
<?php
include('session.php');
include('../config.php');
$qty = $_POST['qty'];
$id = $_POST['cartid'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$image = $_POST['image'];
$description = $_POST['description'];

$cart_item = array(
    "product_id" => $id,
    "name" => $name,
    "price" => $price,
    "quantity" => $qty,
    "image" => $image,
    "description" => $description);

if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
    $count = count($_SESSION['cart']);
    $_SESSION['cart'][$count] = $cart_item;
}else{
    $_SESSION['cart'][0] = $cart_item;
}
include 'cart.php';
?>
```

the code for delete is

```
<?php
session_start();
$key = $_POST['delid'];
echo $key;
unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);  
?>
```

Comment: https://3v4l.org/Gc3e8

Comment: `count()` tells you how many occurances in an array. But when you delete an occurance as the keys are not reorder the keys could be [1,3,4,5]. So count is not a reliable way of knowing what the largest key is as it would tell you 4 in this case. So you would be overwriting cart item 4 which already exists and not adding a new item in occ 6

Comment: thank you,,that was eye opening